# Restarting elastic beanstalk app server from a cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a flask app running on elastic beanstalk. Thre is a cron that runs daily in order to get new data from another server. Once it gets this data, the app server needs to be restarted for it to update with the new data. However, I cannot seem to automate this. I have tried the following lines in my shell script that is run by the cron:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

and

```
/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

However, even though this does restart nginx and also restarts the entire server, the data doesn't update. If I use the EB console and go to Actions > Restart App Server(s), then the new data is loaded and everything works fine. I need this to be part of the cron, or I need to set it to restart the app servers at specific times daily.

How can I do this? I have been looking and trying for days at this point and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: How many servers are running in Elastic Beanstalk?  When you restart by cron is a new one spun up for you?

Comment: Yes, well in the first instance it doesn't take down the server, but in the second it does and it appears as "Pending" in the console for around 5 minutes then it comes back up. If it were creating a new instance, I also have a deploy hook that does the same thing, so that should have updated it. I do know the cron is running because if I check the data on the server after it should run, it is updated. It is just not being used by the app since it needs to be restarted to do so.

Comment: @AndrewR are you able to add your crontab that's able to restart the server? I'm trying to do a similar thing but my crontab doesn't seem to be running thanks.

Comment: @DavidTeather No, I had problems with crontab as well. The only way I can get cron working on EB is via .ebextensions. The instance doesn't think crontab is even running. I did make a bit of progress, but it still isn't running. You can use the AWS admin CLI from lambda to write a function that will restart the app server. I still can't get the async function to work properly, but I think that's the only way to do it. If I manage to get it working I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Resent **AWS blog post** explains how to setup cron on EB:

- [How do I create cron jobs on Amazon EC2 instances in Elastic Beanstalk environments?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/)

Since your question does not contain details about how have you setup the cron, nor any links to documentation used about this, I think its warranted to post the link to bring it to your attention.

Comment: Thanks, but the cron is working just fine. It even restarts the server. The problem is that restarting Nginx or restarting the entire instance does not update the data the in the app that the cron pulled in. Only using the console and hitting "Restart App Server(s)" actually updates the app with the new data. I need to be able to perform that function from the cron.

Answer (score 0):

in `.ebextensions` folder create `cron-linux.config` file with the following code.
(you will likely need to [install aws](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx1WSKcJTgE) on the instance. )

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            date > /tmp/date

            aws elasticbeanstalk restart-app-server --environment-name env-name-here

            exit 0
```

See [here](https://coderssecret.com/how-to-write-cron-jobs-on-aws-ec2-instance/) for setting frequency

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this isn't documented, but simply run:

```
systemctl restart web.service
```

No need for aws CLI (nor the network calls it makes under the covers)

**Note**: this is running on Amazon Linux 2/5.5.3